# MySQL Variables Syntax on Select and Insert Query

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, dynamic-sql, mysql-8.0

I want to regenerate the Source_Table with selected unknown columns only and insert total in the last row.

```
Source_Table
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | name    | unknown_1 | unknown_2 | unknown_3 | unknown_4 | unknown_5 | 
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | ABC     | 12        | 22        | 13        | 14        | 5         | 
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | GHQ     | 16        | 7         | 18        | 9         | 10        | 
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3  | XYZ     | 8         | 14        | 2         | 15        | 20        | 
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I was able to generate a table using dynamic query to get the total in ASC order as follows:

```
Total_Table
+------------+---------+
| supplier   | total   |
+------------+---------+
| unknown_3  | 33      |
+------------+---------+
| unknown_5  | 35      |
+------------+---------+
| unknown_1  | 36      |
+------------+---------+
```

Now, I want to query the `Source_Table` with suppliers listed in `Total_Table` as follows:

```
Query_Result
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| name    | unknown_3 | unknown_5 | unknown_1 | 
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ABC     | 13        | 5         | 12        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| GHQ     | 18        | 10        | 16        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| XYZ     | 2         | 20        | 8         | 
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Total   | 33        | 35        | 36        | 
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I tried the following codes but I am having difficulty with syntax of variables:

```
SET @Supplier1 = (SELECT supplier FROM Total_Table LIMIT 0, 1);
SET @Supplier2 = (SELECT supplier FROM Total_Table LIMIT 1, 1);
SET @Supplier3 = (SELECT supplier FROM Total_Table LIMIT 2, 1);

INSERT INTO Source_Table (name, @Supplier1, @Supplier2, @Supplier3)
VALUES ('Total',
       (SELECT total FROM Total_Table LIMIT 0, 1),
       (SELECT total FROM Total_Table LIMIT 1, 1),
       (SELECT total FROM Total_Table LIMIT 2, 1));  

SELECT name, @Supplier1, @Supplier2, @Supplier3 FROM Source_Table;
```

I tried enclosing it with single/double quotes and backticks but no avail.

What should be the right syntax for variables in these type of codes?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL if you want to have "optional" columns in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not sure if you are referring to my Total_Table above as I already did the dynamic sql in that result using stored procedures. My current issue now is to utilize that Total_Table for my insert and select query. I hope I am getting you right?

Comment: You cannot use variables in the way you hope to AND to be clear your totals table contains the 3 suppliers with the lowest total values in source_table?

Comment: You are right @GordonLinoff. I was able to do it using stored procedures.